# Bicoid regulation of hunchback

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, development

I'm learning about development via the example of *Drosophila* embryogenesis. I understand that bicoid regulates hunchback, among other genes. My question whether the regulation is direct or indirect? In other words, does the level of bicoid directly govern the expression of hunchback, or are there steps in between?

Answer (score 2):

These two papers<sup>[[1]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0092-8674%2889%2990062-7) [[2]](http://www.bio.davidson.edu/COurses/Molbio/restricted/bcd/1989_bicoid.pdf)</sup> argue that *bcd* is a direct activator of *hb*, although be aware that this does not rule out downstream events feeding back to further activate  *hb*. (In fact, given the complexity of the embryonic gene network, it is likely that both mechanisms have a role.)

1. [**Struhl G, Struhl K, Macdonald PM**. 1989. The gradient morphogen *bicoid* is a concentration-dependent transcriptional activator. Cell, 57(7): 1259-1273, doi:10.1016/0092-8674(89)90062-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0092-8674%2889%2990062-7).
2. [Driever W, Nüsslein-Volhard C. 1989. The bicoid protin is a positive regulator of *hunchback* transcription in the early *Drosophila* embryo. Nature, 337: 138-143.](http://www.bio.davidson.edu/COurses/Molbio/restricted/bcd/1989_bicoid.pdf)